# Why is "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features" visible under SharePoint Standard

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Under SharePoint 2010, I'm looking into using the Chart Web Part but it is missing.

According to the site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sp2010devtrainingcourse_developingbiapplicationslab_topic2.aspx it appears that I should enable **SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features** which is already enabled.

[image]

However, we only have SharePoint Standard.

[image]

We obviously aren't able to enable Enterprise without a license, so I'm curious if anyone knows why the option to enable Enterprise features is available if it doesn't actually do anything?

Should this actually do something, or is it just a placeholder that doesn't work until an Enterprise license is entered?

Comment: Intriguing, while I don't have an answer for this, I'm guessing you may have been activated under enterprise in a previous life, or that the site was migrated from an enterprise install to a standard install.  My take is the enterprise features would never work anyways.

Comment: That's probably it. We went from 2007 enterprise to 2010 standard.

Answer (score 1):

Chart Web Parts are only available with enterprise.

If you are looking for a free solution, Amrein offers a free Google Chart Web Part.
http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5749

I have experience using a few of the 3rd party charting tools for SharePoint, my favorite are the charts offered by  Collabion.

http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/ccsp/